# R ddply summarise sum only selected/specific/logical rows

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I have a client loan data base and I want to do a ddply summarise per LoanRefID:

```
    LoanRefId               Tran_Type TransactionAmount
103        11               LoanIssue         1000.0000
104        11           InitiationFee          171.0000
105        11                Interest           59.6729
106        11       AdministrationFee           64.9332
107        11 RaisedClientInstallment         1295.5757
108        11       ClientInstallment         1295.4700
109        11                  PaidUp            0.0000
110        11              Adjustment            0.1361
111        11                  PaidUp            0.0000
112        12               LoanIssue         3000.0000
113        12           InitiationFee          399.0000
114        12                Interest           94.9858
115        12       AdministrationFee           38.6975
116        12 RaisedClientInstallment         3532.6350
117        12       ClientInstallment         3532.6100
118        12                  PaidUp            0.0000
119        12              Adjustment            0.0733
120        12                  PaidUp            0.0000
```

However, I only want to only sum certain rows per loanID. specifically, I only want to sum where the Tran_Type == "ClientInstallment".

The only way I can think of (which doesn't seem to work) is:

```
> ddply(test, c("LoanRefId"), summarise, cash_in = sum(test[test$Tran_Type == "ClientInstallment","TransactionAmount"]))

  LoanRefId cash_in
1        11 4828.08
2        12 4828.08
```

This is not summing per LoanRefId, it is simply summing all amounts where Tran_Type == "CLientInstallment" which is wrong.

Is there a better way to do this logical sum?

Answer (score 3):

Someone may add a `plyr` answer but nowadays `base R`, `dplyr`, or `data.table` are more widely used. plyr has been updated and upgraded. It is worth taking the time to learn the newer implementations as they are more efficient and packed with features.

**base R**

```
aggregate(TransactionAmount ~ LoanRefId, df[df$Tran_Type == "ClientInstallment",], sum)
#  LoanRefId TransactionAmount
#1        11           1295.47
#2        12           3532.61
```

**dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(LoanRefId) %>% 
  filter(Tran_Type == "ClientInstallment") %>%
  summarise(TransactionAmount = sum(TransactionAmount))
#Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
#
#  LoanRefId TransactionAmount
#      (int)             (dbl)
#1        11           1295.47
#2        12           3532.61
```

**data.table**

```
setDT(df)[Tran_Type == "ClientInstallment", sum(TransactionAmount), by=LoanRefId]
#   LoanRefId      V1
#1:        11 1295.47
#2:        12 3532.61
```

Notice how clean `data.table` syntax is :). Great tool to learn.

Comment: Pierre Lafortune, thank you for the detailed answer. I am very new to R and I envy the ability to have 3 ways to achieve the same (complex) thing. If I may abuse your willingness to help once more: I actually need to do `"ClientInstallment" minus "LoanIssue"`. Is this possible using data.tables and/or dplyr?

Comment: Will there always be one of each for each id?

Comment: Good point, I suspect not! In which case I might need to intervene and make both zero so as to not skew my analysis OR clean up the data beforehand by removing those rows?

Comment: Yes it depends on the final result you are looking for. If you determine that subtraction is needed, you can filter by the two values and then subtract as needed.

Comment: Pierre Lafortune, not sure how it is possible, but your dplyr suggestion is not working on my side: `> test %>% 
+     group_by(LoanRefId) %>% 
+     filter(Tran_Type == "ClientInstallment") %>%
+     summarise(TransactionAmount = sum(TransactionAmount))
  TransactionAmount
1           4828.08`

Comment: No, I use your code on the same "test" data and it produces a single total summed number. So there is no grouped by action happening there, weird

Comment: You can post the code you used and the output and we can see what happened. It will most likely be something small that you may have left out.

Comment: I did post the code, again weird. let me give it w/o using the "`": > test %>% 
+     group_by(LoanRefId) %>% 
+     filter(Tran_Type == "ClientInstallment") %>%
+     summarise(TransactionAmount = sum(TransactionAmount))
  TransactionAmount
1           4828.08

Answer (score 2):

Another `base R` option is `tapply`

```
 with(subset(df1, Tran_Type=='ClientInstallment'),
      tapply(TransactionAmount, LoanRefId, FUN=sum))
 #    11      12 
 #1295.47 3532.61
```

Or if we need `plyr` (going back to the past)

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df1, .(LoanRefId), summarise, 
      TransactionAmount = sum(TransactionAmount[Tran_Type=='ClientInstallment']))
#  LoanRefId TransactionAmount
#1        11           1295.47
#2        12           3532.61
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one more possibility, just for completeness:

```
with(df1[df1$Tran_Type=="ClientInstallment",], by(LoanRefId, TransactionAmount, sum))
#TransactionAmount: 1295.47
#[1] 11
#------------------------------------------------------------ 
#TransactionAmount: 3532.61
#[1] 12
```

Answer (score 0):

I honestly felt `data.table` is a life saver.

```
test[Tran_Type == "ClientInstallment", 
     sum(TransactionAmount), by=LoanRefId]
```